# Wemos d1 mini code not uploading

Tags: esp8266, programming, nodemcu, code-review, error

I have a wemos d1 mini. I uploaded a code in wemos d1 mini and after that my wemos mini not working. I tried to upload another code in it even the led blink sketch and even a blank sketch but whenever I tried to do that it just shows connecting but never connects to Arduino ide.[image]
First of all, whenever I tried to connect it to the computer or power it up, its built-in light stays bright and in the serial monitor, it shows garbage characters continuously. [image]But when I connect GPIO 0(d3) of wemos mini to the ground and press the reset button it starts the boot mode and when I upload any code it shows connecting but never upload any code here's the code which uploaded first in it.

```cpp
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
BlynkTimer timer;
 
//Pin assignments
#define switch_1 3 // D5 Pin of NodeMcu
#define switch_2 14 // D6 Pin of NodeMcu
#define switch_3 12 // D7 Pin of NodeMcu
#define switch_4 13
// D0 Pin of NodeMcu
#define button 2
#define relay_1 4 //D1 Pin of NodeMcu
#define relay_2 5 //D2 Pin of NodeMcu
#define relay_3 16 //RX Pin of NodeMcu
#define relay_4 15 //D4 Pin of NodeMcu
 
#define LED1 1 //D0 Pin of NodeMcu
 
int MODE = 0;
 
// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "Android-AP960A";
char pass[] = "talal123";
 
// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "3ueT9aVLvkL60q8piJ6p5Kxx31zZ5xEC";
 
int switch_1_ON = 1;
int switch_2_ON = 1;
int switch_3_ON = 1;
int switch_4_ON = 1;
 
BLYNK_WRITE(V1)
{
int pinValue = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
digitalWrite(relay_1, pinValue); // process received value
}
 
BLYNK_WRITE(V2)
{
int pinValue = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V2 to a variable
digitalWrite(relay_2, pinValue); // process received value
}
BLYNK_WRITE(V3)
{
int pinValue = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
digitalWrite(relay_3, pinValue); // process received value
}
 
BLYNK_WRITE(V4)
{
int pinValue = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V2 to a variable
digitalWrite(relay_4, pinValue); // process received value
}
 
void internet() //When this device connects with internet
{
//**************************************
//Switch 1 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_1) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_1_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, 0);
switch_1_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_1) == LOW )
{
if (switch_1_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_1, HIGH);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, 1);
switch_1_ON = 0;
}
}
//**************************************
//Switch 2 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_2) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_2_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_2, LOW);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, 0);
switch_2_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_2) == LOW )
{
if (switch_2_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_2, HIGH);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, 1);
switch_2_ON = 0;
}
}
//**************************************
//Switch 3 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_3) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_3_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, 0);
switch_3_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_3) == LOW )
{
if (switch_3_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_3, HIGH);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, 1);
switch_3_ON = 0;
}
}
//**************************************
//Switch 4 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_4) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_4_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_4, LOW);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V4, 0);
switch_4_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_4) == LOW )
{
if (switch_4_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_4, HIGH);
Blynk.virtualWrite(V4, 1);
switch_4_ON = 0;
}
}
}
//********************************************
 
void no_internet() //When this device doesn't gets internet
{
//**************************************
//Switch 1 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_1) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_1_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);
switch_1_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_1) == LOW )
{
if (switch_1_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_1, HIGH);
switch_1_ON = 0;
}
}
//**************************************
//Switch 2 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_2) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_2_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_2, LOW);
switch_2_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_2) == LOW )
{
if (switch_2_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_2, HIGH);
switch_2_ON = 0;
}
}
//**************************************
//Switch 3 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_3) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_3_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);
switch_3_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_3) == LOW )
{
if (switch_3_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_3, HIGH);
switch_3_ON = 0;
}
}
//**************************************
//Switch 4 configuration
//**************************************
if (digitalRead(switch_4) == HIGH)
{
if (switch_4_ON == 0 )
{
digitalWrite(relay_4, LOW);
switch_4_ON = 1;
}
}
 
if (digitalRead(switch_4) == LOW )
{
if (switch_4_ON == 1)
{
digitalWrite(relay_4, HIGH);
switch_4_ON = 0;
}
}
}
 
void Blynk_status() // called every 3 seconds by SimpleTimer
{
bool isconnected = Blynk.connected();
if (isconnected == false)
{
MODE = 1;
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
}
if (isconnected == true)
{
MODE = 0;
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
Blynk.syncAll();
}
}
 
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println("n Starting");
pinMode(button, INPUT);
pinMode(switch_1, INPUT);
pinMode(relay_1, OUTPUT);
 
pinMode(switch_2, INPUT);
pinMode(relay_2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(switch_3, INPUT);
pinMode(relay_3, OUTPUT);
 
pinMode(switch_4, INPUT);
pinMode(relay_4, OUTPUT);
 
pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
 
//*****************************************
 
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
delay(200);
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
timer.setInterval(3000L, Blynk_status); // check if connected to Blynk server every 3 seconds
Blynk.config(auth);
}
 
void loop()
{
if ( digitalRead(button) == LOW ) {
WiFiManager wifiManager;
if (!wifiManager.startConfigPortal("Home Automator","1234")) {
Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
delay(3000);
ESP.reset();
delay(3000);
}
Serial.println("connected...:)");
}
if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
{
Blynk.run();
}
 
timer.run(); // Initiates SimpleTimer
if (MODE == 0)
internet();
else
no_internet();
}
```

Please help me. I tried a lot to fix it but nothing happens. I checked the Com port in device manager and all the other necessary settings all were right here are the settings in Arduino ide.[image] Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is wired to the pins of the Wemos?

Comment: Do you have the serial monitor open *while* you're trying to upload?

Comment: yes I also tried to upload code by closing the serial monitor

Comment: no wires are attached to wemos d1 mini

Comment: shorts on headers soldering?

Comment: no shorts on headers I double-checked all connections with multimeter

Comment: You *must not* have the serial monitor open while uploading. It interferes with the communication and the response from the board goes to the serial monitor not to esptool.py.